# URL Rewrite in HTAcess Does Not Work for URL with Parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I mistakenly added `%2Fi` in my URL-

Expected URL: `domainame.com/meaning/kannada/xxxxx`
Current Wrong URL: `domainame.com/meaning/kannada%2Fi/xxxxx`

Now, it has been indexed by Google, and when I see it in my webmaster tool, it shows approximately 4325 URLs with `404`. Now, I would like to add `301` redirection for those URLs. I tried in my HTAccess, but it did not work.

I need- if the URL structure is `domainame.com/meaning/kannada%2Fi/`, then it must be changed to `domainame.com/meaning/kannada/`.

Answer (score 0):

Show us how your redirection in `.htaccess` looks like, but that should work:

```
# Permanent URL redirect
Redirect 301 /meaning/kannada%2Fi/xxxxx http://domainame.com/meaning/kannada/xxxxx
```